# Use ls and awk in python command to mimc bash functionality

Tags: python, bash

I'm trying to use the subprocess command to get a variable defined without spitting stdout, but it's not working as intended.

```
import subprocess

p1 = subprocess.run('ls -lrth /my/data/dir/table.ibd | awk \'{print $5}\'', shell=True, stdout=None)

print ("{0} is the best player.".format(p1))
```

I'm trying to avoide ths os library and use subprocess to gather my output.

The output:

```
79G
CompletedProcess(args="ls -lrth /my/data/dir/table.ibd | awk '{print $5}'", returncode=0) is the size of the table.
```

I want this suppressed, obviously to say "79G is the size of the table." There also shouldn't be any white space before or after the result.

Comment: None of the previous "answers" accommodate for ls options (in this case -lrthS)

Comment: You should not be using `ls` programmatically anyway; it's horribly brittle. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs